# Writing my own MLE command in R is causing issues

Tags: r, optimization, max, stata

I am just really getting into trying to write MLE commands in R that function and look similar to native R functions.  In this attempt I am trying to do a simple MLE with

y=b0 + x*b1 + u

and

u~N(0,sd=s0 + z*s1)

However, even such a simple command I am having difficulty coding.  I have written a similar command in [Stata in a handful of lines](http://www.econometricsbysimulation.com/2012/11/estimating-random-coefficients-on-x.html.)

Here is the code I have written so far in R.

```
  normalreg <- function (beta, sigma=NULL, data, beta0=NULL, sigma0=NULL,
                         con1 = T, con2 = T) {

    # If a formula for sigma is not specified 
    #  assume it is the same as the formula for the beta.
    if (is.null(sigma)) sigma=beta

    # Grab the call expression
    mf <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)

    # Find the position of each argument
    m <- match(c("beta", "sigma", "data", "subset", "weights", "na.action", 
                 "offset"), names(mf), 0L)

    # Adjust names of mf
    mf <- mf[c(1L, m)]

    # Since I have two formulas I will call them both formula
    names(mf)[2:3] <- "formula"

    # Drop unused levels
    mf$drop.unused.levels <- TRUE

    # Divide mf into data1 and data2
    data1  <- data2 <- mf
     data1 <- mf[-3]
     data2 <- mf[-2]

    # Name the first elements model.frame which will be 
    data1[[1L]] <- data2[[1L]] <- as.name("model.frame")

    data1 <- as.matrix(eval(data1, parent.frame()))
    data2 <- as.matrix(eval(data2, parent.frame()))

    y     <- data1[,1]
    data1 <- data1[,-1]
     if (con1)  data1 <- cbind(data1,1)
    data2 <- unlist(data2[,-1])
      if (con2) data2 <- cbind(data2,1)

    data1 <- as.matrix(data1) # Ensure our data is read as matrix
    data2 <- as.matrix(data2) # Ensure our data is read as matrix

    if (!is.null(beta0)) if (length(beta0)!=ncol(data1))
      stop("Length of beta0 need equal the number of ind. data2iables in the first equation")

    if (!is.null(sigma0)) if (length(sigma0)!=ncol(data2)) 
      stop("Length of beta0 need equal the number of ind. data2iables in the second equation")

    # Set initial parameter estimates
    if (is.null(beta0))  beta0   <- rep(1, ncol(data1))
    if (is.null(sigma0)) sigma0 <- rep(1, ncol(data2))

    # Define the maximization function
    normMLE <- function(est=c(beta0,sigma0), data1=data1, data2=data2, y=y) {          
      data1est <- as.matrix(est[1:ncol(data1)], nrow=ncol(data1))
      data2est <- as.matrix(est[(ncol(data1)+1):(ncol(data1)+ncol(data2))],
                              nrow=ncol(data1))

      ps <-pnorm(y-data1%*%data1est, 
                       sd=data2%*%data2est)
      # Estimate a vector of log likelihoods based on coefficient estimates
      llk <- log(ps)
      -sum(llk) 
    }

    results <- optim(c(beta0,sigma0), normMLE, hessian=T,
                     data1=data1, data2=data2, y=y)

    results
  }


  x <-rnorm(10000)
  z<-x^2
  y <-x*2 + rnorm(10000, sd=2+z*2) + 10

  normalreg(y~x, y~z)
```

At this point the biggest issue is finding an optimization routine that does not fail when the some of the values return NA when the standard deviation goes negative.  Any suggestions?  Sorry for the huge amount of code.

[Francis](http://www.econometricsbysimulation.com)

Comment: You could use a `log()` / `exp()` trick to force the sd positive.  Obviously the sd can't be negative, so doesn't it kind of make sense that this would throw an error?  When you supply the initial values to R, log transform them first (e.g., you think sd=5, so supply `log(5)`). Inside the MLE function, expnentiate the sd (so `exp()` the `log(5)`).  This forces it positive.  When you go to interpret the model fit, again take the `log()` of the estimate.

Comment: Good idea.  I tried playing with abs() and though it seemed to correct this particular problem of having NAs it did not converge on anything close to the true parameters despite increasing the sample.  This indicates to me that I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I think that the BFGS option in optim() let's you set parameter constraints.  However, there's no guarantee that this will help.You might just need to take a closer look at the model and data, and see if the model is formulated appropriately.  I can't say for sure though.

Comment: So why does your `Stata` code NOT produce negative sd values, or why does it not blow up when processing such values?  What calculations or "safety checks" are different in your `R` code?

Comment: I would really like to know the answer to this question because this seems to argue that despite my preference for R that I should probably to doing my analysis with Stata.

Comment: one small point here is that the OP should be using `dnorm()` rather than `pnorm()` ... and I would say that this could be done pretty easily in the `bbmle` package too ...

Comment: Couldn't you just modify the function to give a likelihood of 0 if the parameter estimates aren't in the parameter space?  Seems like an easy enough check at the beginning of the function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I include a check to see if any of the standard deviations are less than or equal to 0 and return a likelihood of 0 if that is the case.  Seems to work for me.  You can figure out the details of wrapping it into your function.

```
#y=b0 + x*b1 + u
#u~N(0,sd=s0 + z*s1)

ll <- function(par, x, z, y){
    b0 <- par[1]
    b1 <- par[2]
    s0 <- par[3]
    s1 <- par[4]
    sds <- s0 + z*s1
    if(any(sds <= 0)){
        return(log(0))
    }

    preds <- b0 + x*b1

    sum(dnorm(y, preds, sds, log = TRUE))
}

n <- 100
b0 <- 10
b1 <- 2
s0 <- 2
s1 <- 2
x <- rnorm(n)
z <- x^2
y <- b0 + b1*x + rnorm(n, sd = s0 + s1*z)

optim(c(1,1,1,1), ll, x=x, z=z,y=y, control = list(fnscale = -1))
```

With that said it probably wouldn't be a bad idea to parameterize the standard deviation in such a way that it is impossible to go negative...